# Proving $\tan x$ is surjective

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I'm trying to make sure that I understand the argument that $f(x) = \tan x$ is surjective. It should follow from the following these facts: (1) intermediate value theorem ($\tan x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$); (2) $f(x)$ approaches $+\infty$ as $x \to - \frac{\pi}{2}$ from the right; and (3) $f(x)$ approaches $-\infty$ as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ from the left.

My understanding of the argument is this. Let's pick $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^{-}} f(x) = + \infty$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that $x > \delta$ implies $f(x) > y$. Since $\lim\limits_{x \to - \frac{\pi}{2}^{+}} f(x) = -\infty$, there exists $\eta > 0$ so that $x < \eta$ implies $f(x) < \eta$. $\tan(x)$ is defined and continuous on these intervals, so might block out an interval $\left[\eta - \epsilon, \delta + \epsilon\right]$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. At $\delta + \epsilon$, $f(x) > y$. At $\eta - \epsilon$, $f(x) < y$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is some $x$ in the interval satisfying $f(x) = y$. As $y$ was arbitrary, we can repeat this for any $y$.

How does this look?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: You have things switched --- as $x \to (\pi/2)^{-}$ we have $\tan(x) \to +\infty.$ [And goes to minus infinity when approaching $-\pi/2$ from the right.] But if you adjust your argument for this it works.

Comment: This is a very good point. Thank you for pointing that out. Is it otherwise correct?

Comment: Otherwise correct.

Answer (score 1):

While you may have the right idea, given the corrections coffeemath pointed out, your write-up of it makes several mistakes. Some of these may just be typos, but others appear to be deeper.

> ($\tan x$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$)

No it isn't. It is not even defined on all of $\Bbb R$. But it is continuous on $\left(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right)$

> Let's pick $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\lim\limits_{x \to
> \frac{\pi}{2}^{-}} f(x) = + \infty$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ so
> that $x > \delta$ implies $f(x) > y$.

You are taking the limit at $x \to \frac \pi2 -$, not as $x \to \infty$. There is $\delta > 0$ such that if $\frac \pi2 - \delta < x < \frac \pi2$, then $f(x) > y$.

> Since $\lim\limits_{x \to -
> \frac{\pi}{2}^{+}} f(x) = -\infty$, there exists $\eta > 0$ so that $x
> < \eta$ implies $f(x) < \eta$.

Again, the limit is as $x \to -\frac \pi 2+$, not as $x \to -\infty$ (and of course it is $f(x) < y$, not $\eta$). There is $\eta > 0$ such that if $-\frac \pi2 < x < -\frac \pi2 + \eta$, then $f(x) < y$.

> $\tan(x)$ is defined and continuous on these intervals, so might block out an interval $\left[\eta -
> \epsilon, \delta + \epsilon\right]$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. At
> $\delta + \epsilon$, $f(x) > y$. At $\eta - \epsilon$, $f(x) < y$. By
> the intermediate value theorem, there is some $x$ in the interval
> satisfying $f(x) = y$. As $y$ was arbitrary, we can repeat this for
> any $y$.

Obviously, the interval needs corrected to $\left[-\frac \pi 2 + \epsilon, \frac \pi 2 - \epsilon\right]$, where $0 < \epsilon < \delta, \eta$. Otherwise, it is correct. However it could be stated more cleanly as

- Let $-\frac\pi 2 < a < -\frac\pi 2 + \eta, \frac\pi 2 - \delta < b < \frac\pi 2$, then $f(a) < y < f(b)$ and by the intermediate value theorem, there is an $x \in [a,b]$ with $f(x) = y$. As $y$ was arbitrary, we can repeat this for
  any $y$.